# print stdout of a subprocess command in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, popen

I am having problems in displaying the output of a command run with Python subprocess.Popen within a docker container. The terminal just hangs while the process is running and only at the end it prints out the output.
I have a Python script like this (simplified):

```py
def test():
  print('start')
  process = subprocess.Popen('pytest', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
  for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(">>> {}".format(line.rstrip()))

def docker():
  client = docker.from_env()
  command = './this_script --test'
  generator = client.containers.run('python:3', command, remove=True, init=True, working_dir='/test', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
  for log in generator:
    print('>>> {}'.format(log))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  ...
  # if called with --test, the script calls test()
  # if called with --docker, the script calls docker()
```

Even the `print('start')` at the beginning of `test()` is not printed until the end of the process.

How can I force the stdout of the subprocess to be displayed real time?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, using Python 3.6.7, Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77.

**EDIT**:
So the problem is that the "run" command hangs and does not return until the container process has ended.
I found a way to make it work by running the container in detached mode:

- Added the -u flag in the shebang
- Updated the `docker()` function to start the container in detached mode:

```
def docker():
  client = docker.from_env()
  command = 'python -u this_script.py --test'
  generator = client.containers.run('python:3', command, remove=True, init=True, working_dir='/test', detach=True)
  for log in generator.logs(stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True):
    print('>>> {}'.format(log))
```

Comment: Try using the `-u` flag, when running the python script inside your container.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I changed the command in ``docker()`` to ``command = python -u this_script.py --test``. I have also tried to add the -u in the shebang or to call the script from my terminal with ``python3 -u this_script.py --docker``. Stil same problem.